# Norm of a mapping

Tags: normed-spaces

$$C[0,1]=\{f:[0,1]\rightarrow R | \text{$f$ is continuous function}\}$$
$$\|f\|=\max \{|f(x)|:x\in [0,1]\}$$
$$A:(C[0,1],\|\|)\rightarrow(C[0,1],\|\|)$$
$$A(f)(x)=(x^4-x^2)f(x)$$

I have to determine a norm of a mapping $A$.
By definition
$$\|A\|=\inf\{M:|A|\leq M\|f\|\}$$
I first show that $A(f)(x)$ is bounded.
$$|A(f)(x)|=|x^4-x^2||f(x)|\leq|x^4-x^2|\|f(x)\|$$

Now I have $$\|A\|=\inf\{M:|A|\leq M\|f\|\}\leq |x^4-x^2|$$
If I choose $f(x)$ such that $|A(f)(x)|=|x^4-x^2|$ and $\|f(x)\|=1$ (for example $f(x)$=1), I have
$$|A(f)(x)|=|x^4-x^2||f(x)|=|x^4-x^2|\cdot 1=|x^4-x^2|\leq M\|f(x)\|=M$$

Hence, all $M$ is $\geq|x^4-x^2|\implies \inf M\geq|x^4-x^2|$
From above we know that $\inf M\leq |x^4-x^2|$
$\implies M=|x^4-x^2|\implies \|A(f)(x)\|=|x^4-x^2|$

Is this OK? May $\|A\|$ be variable or it has to be fixed number?

Comment: No, $\|A\|$ should be a number. Find an upper bound for the expression $|x^4-x^2|$.

Comment: $(x^4-x^2)'=4x^3-2x=2x(2x^2-1)$. This is equal to zero when $2x^2-1=0$ i.e. $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$. Hence, $|x^4-x^2|\leq \frac{1}{2}$. Is this ok?

Comment: Yes. You should also check the endpoints of the interval, but $x^4-x^2=0$ at the endpoints.

Comment: And everything else is correct?

Comment: @njguliyev If norm of $A$ is a number, let's say $\|A\|=a\in R$, how can I check if $A$ is contraction? I have to check if there exists $\lambda\in[0,1)$ such that $$\|A(f)-A(g)\|\leq\lambda \|f)x)-g(x)\|$$ $$\|A(f)-A(g)\|=a$$ since $A$ is linear mapping and $A(f)-A(g)=A(f-g)$. So, I'm looking for $\lambda\in[0,1)$ such that $$a\leq\lambda\max\{|f(x)-g(x):x\in[0,1]\}$$

Comment: $\|Ax\|$ (for some $x$) and $\|A\|$ are different expressions. $\|Af-Ag\|$ depends on $f-g$.

Comment: Where did I write $\|Ax\|$? Is anything what I've done correct? How should I check if $A(f)(x)$ is contraction?

Comment: You found that $\|A\|=1/2$. Therefore
$$\|A(f-g)\| \le \frac12 \|f-g\|.$$
This means you can choose $\lambda=1/2$ and $A$ is a contraction mapping.

Comment: How can I be sure that $$\|A(f-g)\| \le \frac12 \|f-g\|?$$ $\|A(f-g)\|=\frac{1}{2}$, right? What if $\|f-g\|<1$?